# onFinalize listener in flutter with firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

Hi I'm developing an app that uploads an image to firebase storage, then cloud function elaborates it and it returns another image.
I would know when the elaborated image is ready. In android there's [onFinalize listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events). Is there something like it in flutter?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page of documentation you're linking to has nothing to do with Android or any mobile platform.  That's a Cloud Functions trigger, and it only works with code deployed to Cloud Functions.  There is no way to emulate this behavior in a mobile client.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! The only way to emulate this behavior is to check periodically if there's the file?

Comment: If you know the name of the file, yes.  The trigger can use wildcards without knowing the name of the file, which is something you can't do in a mobile client.